# LINQ merge two grouped query results

Tags: c#, linq

in my domain I have an object called "Block". A "Block" can have "Pins" and "Attributes" attached to it.

I can create two groups which give me the following results:

Group1 is:

```
Block:B1
    Pin:P1
    Pin:P2
Block:B2
    Pin:P3
    Pin:P4
```

Group2 is:

```
Block:B1
    Attribute:Att1, Value: Value1
    Attribute:Att2, Value: Value2
Block:B2
    Attribute:Att3, Value: Value3
    Attribute:Att4, Value: Value4
```

now I like to merge this two results to something like this:

Resulting group is:

```
Block:B1
    Pin:P1
    Pin:P2
    Attribute:Att1, Value: Value1
    Attribute:Att2, Value: Value2
Block:B2
    Pin:P3
    Pin:P4
    Attribute:Att3, Value: Value3
    Attribute:Att4, Value: Value4
```

Is that possible with LINQ? Or do I need un-grouped results to create a grouped result later?

Thanks

EDIT:
With Road242 solution I get this result:

```
Pin: P1
Pin: P2
Attribute: Att1
Attribute: Att2
Pin: P3
Pin: P4
Attribute: Att3
Attribute: Att4
```

The pins and attributes look pretty good, but I lost the blocks as grouping key :-(

EDIT:
My queries look like this:

```
var blockPinsQuery = from blockPinRelation in blockPinRelations
            join block in blocks
                on blockPinRelation.BlockId equals block.Id
            join pin in pins
                on blockPinRelation.PinId equals pin.Id
            group pin by block
            into g
            select new
                   {
                       Block = g.Key,
                       Pins = g
                   };
```

and

```
var blockAttributesQuery = from blockAttributeRelation in blockAttributeRelations
                             join block in blocks
                                 on blockAttributeRelation.BlockId equals block.Id
                             join attribute in stringAttributes
                                 on blockAttributeRelation.AttributeId equals attribute.Id
                                   group attribute by block
                                 into g
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     Block = g.Key,
                                     Attributes = g
                                 };
```

as you can see there is a relation-table in between the relevant entities. But this is not important, I guess.

My output routines look like this:

```
foreach (var group in blockPinsQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Block:" + group.Block.Name);
            group.Pins.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("\t" + "Pin:" + x.Name));
        }
```

and

```
foreach (var group in blockAttributesQuery)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Block:" + group.Block.Name);
            group.Attributes.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("\t" + "Attribute:" + x.Name + ", " + "Value: " + x.Value));
        }
```

and for Road242 query:

```
foreach (var group in joinedResults)
        {
            group.Pins.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("Pin: " + p.Name));
            group.Attributes.ToList().ForEach(p => Console.WriteLine("Attribute: " + p.Name));
        }
```

Comment: could you please post the declartion of Block, in order to see it's properties etc. Thanks

Comment: Use `Union` with strong typed return, instead of anonymous..

Comment: @ André Figueiredo: I was trying to use Union(). As you mentioned Union() requires a strong typed return value, but I don't see how to accomplish that. How do I use strong typed return value?

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq join clause:

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

```
var joinedResults =
    from g1 in Group1
    join g2 in Group2 on g1.Block equals g2.Block
    select new { Pin = g1.Pin, Attribute = g2.Attribute };
```